# Responsive image in wordpress html and css

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, responsive

I'm trying to have a responsive image while doing it on wordpress but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
<img class="alignheader wp-image-3295" src="image/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/banner-02-1-300x66.png" alt="" width="1920" height="424" /> 

<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="#"><img src="image/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/banner-09.png" alt="" width="500" height="&quot;289" /></a>

<a href="#"><img src="image/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/banner-10.png" alt="" width="500" height="&quot;289/" /></a></div> 

<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="#"> <img src="image/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/banner-4x.png" alt="bottom" class="alignbottom" />
```

This is the css i have

```
.alignbottom { width: 100vh; 
height: 20vh; 
border: 3px solid tomato; 
object-fit: cover;
object-position: 0 0; }
```

Comment: This is the html I have :  <img src="http://image/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/banner-4x.png" alt="bottom" class="alignbottom"/>

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
    #img1{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: 3px solid tomato;
        object-fit: cover;
        object-position: 0 0;
    }
    .img-div{
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px
    }
</style>
</head>
    <div class="img-div">
        <img id="img1" src="YOUR_IMAGE_URL" />
    </div>
</html>
```

main is: `object-fit: cover;`

Comment: Hi sorry, I've tried and only the red box is responsive. the image stays at the same size but it isn't responsive :( 

This is what I have
.alignbottom {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 20vh;
  border: 3px solid tomato;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 0 0;
} I can't use img as I have other images that i do not want it to be responsive

Comment: can you post the whole html part & css part here, then it will be easy to tell.

Comment: and img in css is just an example, you can give it a seperate id and use that id in css.

Comment: HTML :
<img class="alignheader wp-image-3295" src="http://image/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/banner-02-1-300x66.png" alt="" width="1920" height="424" />
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="#"><img src="http://image/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/banner-09.png" alt="" width="500" height="&quot;289" /></a><a href="#"><img src="http://image/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/banner-10.png" alt="" width="500" height="&quot;289/" /></a></div>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="#">
<img src="http://image/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/banner-4x.png" alt="bottom" class="alignbottom" />

Comment: CSS : .alignbottom {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 20vh;
  border: 3px solid tomato;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 0 0;
}

Comment: please edit your answer with your code, that will be easy to read than here on comments

Comment: check my answer i've edited with the new code, and if worked for you then please mark this an answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry it isnt solved yet. same issue, image size is same as mobile (which is good) but it isn't aligned to centre for mobile

Comment: have you checked the new code in my answer? if not, then try that.

Comment: Yes, I've checked the new code in your answer

Comment: You need a parent div for the img element, "like i  have shown in my edited answer" give specific width and height to that div and change your css for img to "width: 100%; height: 100%"

Comment: Yes, I've gave specific width and height to the div, as well as css img to width: 100% height 100%. But it doesn't work as well

Comment: HTML in your question doesn't seem to have a parent div for img. update your current code in your question.